# How do I use the jQuery click method to show hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a pretty basic question, but I've been working at it for a while and can't figure out the solution.

I have a series of `<li>` items in an HTML document. At the end of each, I have a button that I want to, when clicked, show some hidden text.

```
<ol>
    <li>Click this button to show hidden text <button>Click</button>
    <p style="display:none;">Some text</p></li>
</ol>
```

Since I have a series of these `<li>`, I figured the easiest way to do this is having each button click show the nearest hidden element through JQuery

Here's the JQuery code I've been trying to use:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('p.pages').nextUntil('li').toggle('slow');
});
```

To be honest, I'm not sure I'm using the right JQuery method to do this, but I've tried looking through the JQuery docs and it seems like this best fits what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you looking for is

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').toggle('slow');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/D3B5g/)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with the code you presented.

You're using the `p.pages` selector, which looks for a `<p>` with `class="pages"`.  You'll find nothing in your document with this selector.

Another problem is that because you're using the `$('button')` selector, this will apply to all `<button>`s on your page, not just buttons in that list.

Next, you're looking for elements *after* the `<p>`, when you're actually trying to toggle the `<p>` itself.

The last problem is that this code will only support one such item.  You're not specifying *which* `<p>` to select, so when you click any button on your page you'll hide the first `<p>`, even if the button is further down the list.

#### Solution

I would assign a class to the button to select it, in case you have different button types.

I'd also use the `$(this)` (for the button), and `.next('p')` to find the `p` right after the specific button you pushed.

Then I'd remove the CSS `display` using `.css('display', 'inherit')`.  Or use `.toggle('slow')` like in your original question:

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swmvH/).

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>Click this button to show hidden text
      <button class="makeVisible">Click</button>
      <p style="display:none;">Some text</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
$('button.makeVisible').click(function() {
    $(this).next('p').css('display','inherit');
    // or: $(this).next('p').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I forgot about the "pages" class I was trying to use, I should have taken that out before posting this up.

Comment: @ghindo: I know you accepted another answer, so no worries there.  But if this was useful please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function() {

$(this).next().toggle('slow'); });
```